# Use bash to extract number from between square brackets

Tags: command-line, bash, python

My file looks like this:

```
[581]((((((((501:0.00024264,451:0.00024264):0.000316197,310:0.000558837):0.00857295,((589:0.000409158,538:0.000409158):0.000658084,207:0.00106724
):0.00806454):0.0429702,(((198:0.00390205,91:0.00390205):0.016191,79:0.0200931):0.0147515,(187:0.00133008,50:0.00133008):0.0335145):0.0172574):0.
127506,((140:0.00253019,117:0.00253019):0.0533693,(((533:0.00728707,(463:8.80494e-05,450:8.80494e-05):0.00719902):0.0217722,389:0.0290593):0.0253
931,(((141:0.018004,107:0.018004):0.0143861,(111:0.00396127,(106:0.00161229,12:0.00161229):0.00234898):0.0284289):0.0145736,(129:0.0195982,((123:
0.0105973,66:0.0105973):0.0084867,10:0.019084):0.000514243):0.0273656):0.00748854):0.00144709):0.123708):0.000944439,((181:0.00108761,71:0.00108761):0.0819772);  
[50]((((((((501:0.00024264,451:0.00024264):0.000316197,310:0.000558837):0.00857295,((589:0.000409158,538:0.000409158):0.000658084,207:0.00106724):0.00806454):0.0429702,(((198:0.00390205,91:0.00390205):0.016191,79:0.0200931):0.0147515,(187:0.00133008,50:0.00133008):0.0335145):0.0172574):0.127506,((140:0.00253019,117:0.00253019):0.0533693,(((533:0.00728707,(463:8.80494e-05,450:8.80494e-05):0.00719902):0.0217722,389:0.0290593):0.0253931,(((141:0.018004,107:0.018004):0.0143861,(111:0.00396127,(106:0.00161229,12:0.00161229):0.00234898):0.0284289):0.0145736,(129:0.0195982,((123:0.0105973,66:0.0105973):0.0084867,10:0.019084):0.000514243):0.0273656):0.00748854):0.00144709):0.123708):0.000944439,((181:0.00108761,71:0.00108761):0.0819772);
```

Every new line starts with the pattern `[number]`. Every line ends with the pattern `);`.

I need to extract the numbers in the square brackets from the beginning of every line, and write them into a new file. I don't know how many lines the file has beforehand.

Comment: In your example, not every line starting with [num], not every line ending with ); ..perhaps lost while formatting.. Make it right please..

Comment: @user3069326 Do you want to match only from lines that end in `);`? Out of the six lines you've shown us, only 2 end that way, only 2 start with a number in `[` `]` brackets, and only 1 line both starts with a number in `[` `]` brackets and ends in `);`. Or do you mean you actually want a method that *ignores* line breaks and instead treats `);` like a line break? If you want to split on `);` rather than newlines, you should either [edit] your question to clarify that, or post a new one--which might be better since there are already 5 answers posted based on your question as originally asked.

Comment: @User3069626 Don't damage posts please.

Comment: the qs were off topic it shoudl eb delted

Comment: @user no it shouldn't. We leave it around. Also, I've voted to reopen it. Just because it's closed doesn't mean it won't help someone.

Comment: no thsi is against the rules..this shoudl be delted..nd i will need to report that behviour

Comment: No, it shouldn't be deleted, it's not off topic (it seems to have been closed incorrectly).  Do not attempt to delete this. Even if it is off topic *it should not be deleted*. If you continue to remove it I will flag for moderator.

Answer (score 12):

You can achieve this with just a single [`grep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/grep.1.html) command. This is because GNU grep lets you use a [Perl regular expression](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/perlre.1.html) (`-P`), which supports [zero-width lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (`\K` and `(?=` `)`, in this case):

```bash
grep -oP '^\[\K\d+(?=\])' infile
```

As written, that will send the output to your terminal. To redirect it to a file, use:

```bash
grep -oP '^\[\K\d+(?=\])' infile > outfile
```

This method has the advantage of brevity and simplicity. It matches text that

- is preceded by (`\K`)

  - a `[` character(`\[`) -- `\` is needed as `[` otherwise has a special meaning in regular expressions
  - that appears at the beginning of a line (`^`);
- consists of one or more (`+`) digits (`\d`);
- is followed by (`(?=` `)`)

  - a `]` character (`\]`) -- like with `[`, `\` forces `]` to be matched literally.

Comment: Nice, indeed. :)

Comment: can you tell me how you woudl paste that in R? when i try paste("grep -oP '^\[\K\d+(?=\])' infile > outfile") I get Error: '\[' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""grep -oP '^\["
>

Comment: +1..need to mention that if OP wants to match the lines ending with `);` too, then the positive lookahead pattern `(?=\].*\);$)`

Comment: @user3069326 If R says `Error: 'xyz' is an unrecognized escape in character string`, you can escape the first character of the problematic text with a \. This fixes the problem fully or gives a new error about later text. In your case, put a \ before `[`. For me R does something else: `paste("grep -oP '^[\K\d+(?=])' infile > outfile")` produces `Error: '\K' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""grep -oP '^[\K"` and `paste("grep -oP '^[\\K\\d+(?=])' infile > outfile")` succeeds. I know only a little about R; I don't know why my R and yours seem to behave differently.

Answer (score 7):

Using `sed`:

- `< inputfile sed -n 's/^\[\([0-9]*\)\].*$/\1/p' > out`

---

**Command breakdown**:

- `< inputfile`: redirects the content of `inputfile` to `stdin`
- `-n`: suppresses output
- `> out`: redirects the content of `stdout` to `out`

**Regex breakdown**:

- `s`: performs a substitution
- `/`: starts the regex
- `^`: matches the start of the line
- `\[`: matches a `[` character
- `\(`: starts the capturing group
- `[0-9]*`: matches any number of digits
- `\)`: stops the capturing group
- `\]`: matches a `]` character
- `.*`: matches any number of any character
- `$`: matches the end of the line
- `/`: stops the regex / starts the replacement
- `\1`: replaces with the first capturing group
- `/`: stops the replacement
- `p`: prints only the matching lines

---

Using `grep`+`tr` (if you need a method that runs both on Ubuntu and on another OS whose `grep` doesn't support PCRE--otherwise, refer to [Eliah Kagan's `grep`-only version](https://askubuntu.com/a/621061/380067)):

- `< inputfile grep -o '^\[[0-9]*\]' | tr -d '[]' > out`

**Command breakdown**:

- `< inputfile` in `grep`: redirects the content of `inputfile` to `stdin`
- `-o` in `grep`: prints only the match
- `-d` in `tr`: deletes the characters
- `> out` in `tr`: redirects the content of `stdout` to `out`

**Regex breakdown**:

- `^`: matches the start of the line
- `\[`: matches a `[` character
- `[0-9]*`: matches any number of digits
- `\]`: matches a `]` character

Comment: @kos I think the `grep`/`tr` way is valuable and interesting. Unless there's some bug in it, I hope you put it (or something like it) back--of course it's your choice. While [the `grep`-only way I posted](https://askubuntu.com/a/621061) may often be preferable, sometimes one wishes to write a command that is portable to systems whose `grep` doesn't support Perl regular expressions (as is the case for most implementations other than GNU grep). You could separate the `grep`/`tr` way out into a separate, second section if you don't want it to distract from your primary recommended method.

Comment: @EliahKagan Yes, I've removed it because your version was better, also I tought that any `grep` version builtin in Ubuntu supports PCREs, but overall you're right it definetly can't hurt, I'm restoring it.

Answer (score 3):

the `perl` way:

```
perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if /^\[([0-9]*)\].*/' testdata > out
```

or with `awk`:

```
awk 'match($0, /^\[[0-9]*\]/) {print substr($0, RSTART + 1, RLENGTH - 2)}' testdata > out
```

---

Used Regex in both cases:

```
^\[[0-9]*\]
```

Explanation

- `/^\[[0-9]*\]/`

  - `^` assert position at start of the string
  - `\[` matches the character `[` literally
  - `[0-9]*` match a single character present in the list below

    - Quantifier: `*` Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
    - `0-9` a single character in the range between 0 and 9
  - `\]` matches the character `]` literally

  [image: Regular expression visualization]
  <sub>(source: [debuggex.com](https://www.debuggex.com/i/NzA3VTAzanj9VnR8.png))</sub>

  <sub>[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/NzA3VTAzanj9VnR8)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Use this in Bash:

```
 grep -oh '\[[0-9].*\]' mytestfile | sed 's/.*\[\([^]]*\)\].*/\1/g' > myresultfile
```

Comment: Why `-h`? `grep` only prints filenames when there is more than one input file.

Comment: Extra protection against multiple inputs (this is my habit in cases like this).

Answer (score 1):

`python` solution using `re` module and considering two situations :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import re
with open('/path/to/file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        digits_case_1 = re.search(r'(?<=^\[)\d+(?=\])', line)
        digits_case_2 = re.search(r'(?<=^\[)\d+(?=\].*\);$)', line)
        if digits_case_1:
            print 'Not considering ");" at end: ' + digits_case_1.group()
        if digits_case_2:
            print 'Considering ");" at end: ' + digits_case_2.group()
```

**Output :**

```
Not considering ");" at end: 581
Not considering ");" at end: 50
Considering ");" at end: 50
```

Here i have considered two situations as your question does not seem clear to me.

- `digits_case_1` will print the digits match between `[]` at the start of the line, it will not consider whether the line is ending with `);` or not.
- `digits_case_2` will print digits between `[]` at the start of the line only if the line is ending with `);`.

Answer (score 0):

`cat $FILE | awk -F\] '{ print $1 }' | grep '\[' | tr -d '['`

Where the progression is:<sup>§</sup>

```
$ FILE=/tmp/tmp.tmp

$ cat $FILE
[581]((((((((501:0.00024264,451:0.00024264):0.000316197,310:0.000558837):0.00857295,((589:0.000409158,538:0.000409158):0.000658084,207:0.00106724
):0.00806454):0.0429702,(((198:0.00390205,91:0.00390205):0.016191,79:0.0200931):0.0147515,(187:0.00133008,50:0.00133008):0.0335145):0.0172574):0.
127506,((140:0.00253019,117:0.00253019):0.0533693,(((533:0.00728707,(463:8.80494e-05,450:8.80494e-05):0.00719902):0.0217722,389:0.0290593):0.0253
931,(((141:0.018004,107:0.018004):0.0143861,(111:0.00396127,(106:0.00161229,12:0.00161229):0.00234898):0.0284289):0.0145736,(129:0.0195982,((123:
0.0105973,66:0.0105973):0.0084867,10:0.019084):0.000514243):0.0273656):0.00748854):0.00144709):0.123708):0.000944439,((181:0.00108761,71:0.00108761):0.0819772);
[50]((((((((501:0.00024264,451:0.00024264):0.000316197,310:0.000558837):0.00857295,((589:0.000409158,538:0.000409158):0.000658084,207:0.00106724):0.00806454):0.0429702,(((198:0.00390205,91:0.00390205):0.016191,79:0.0200931):0.0147515,(187:0.00133008,50:0.00133008):0.0335145):0.0172574):0.127506,((140:0.00253019,117:0.00253019):0.0533693,(((533:0.00728707,(463:8.80494e-05,450:8.80494e-05):0.00719902):0.0217722,389:0.0290593):0.0253931,(((141:0.018004,107:0.018004):0.0143861,(111:0.00396127,(106:0.00161229,12:0.00161229):0.00234898):0.0284289):0.0145736,(129:0.0195982,((123:0.0105973,66:0.0105973):0.0084867,10:0.019084):0.000514243):0.0273656):0.00748854):0.00144709):0.123708):0.000944439,((181:0.00108761,71:0.00108761):0.0819772);

$ cat $FILE | awk -F\] '{ print $1 }'
[581
):0.00806454):0.0429702,(((198:0.00390205,91:0.00390205):0.016191,79:0.0200931):0.0147515,(187:0.00133008,50:0.00133008):0.0335145):0.0172574):0.
127506,((140:0.00253019,117:0.00253019):0.0533693,(((533:0.00728707,(463:8.80494e-05,450:8.80494e-05):0.00719902):0.0217722,389:0.0290593):0.0253
931,(((141:0.018004,107:0.018004):0.0143861,(111:0.00396127,(106:0.00161229,12:0.00161229):0.00234898):0.0284289):0.0145736,(129:0.0195982,((123:
0.0105973,66:0.0105973):0.0084867,10:0.019084):0.000514243):0.0273656):0.00748854):0.00144709):0.123708):0.000944439,((181:0.00108761,71:0.00108761):0.0819772);
[50

$ cat $FILE | awk -F\] '{ print $1 }' | grep '\['
[581
[50

$ cat $FILE | awk -F\] '{ print $1 }' | grep '\[' | tr -d '['
581
50

$
```

<sup>§</sup> For those without access to the `man` command.

Comment: You don't need to pipe from `cat`, since `awk` accepts an input filename as an argument: `awk -F\] '{ print $1 }' $FILE | grep '\[' | tr -d '['`

Comment: Maybe you could improve your answer by explaining what each part of your command line does? Thank you!